# How to set pattern matching in IIS 10?

Tags: iis

I need to handle specifically some requests on IIS 10 based on the user_agent. So I created a set of rules as follows:

[image]

Now I need to add a new condition like :

```
{HTTP_USER_AGENT} matches the pattern *Something* AND not the pattern *SomethingElse*
```

This should be in the same condition in order not to change the logic of the other conditions.

How can I do that?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, If you want to negate the condition, you can use the negated attribute. A pattern can be negated by using the negate attribute. when this attribute is used, the rule action is performed only if the current URL does not match the specified pattern.

Comment: @samwu thanks for your comment. My question is more about the syntax. How can I have a pattern to match *something* and not *somethingelse* ? Do you have an idea please ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean, please post more details information about your requirement.